# Win32Exception: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: java, password-encryption

I am making an application that displays ur saved browser password(s) (right now I'm using Google Chrome) in an easy way. Everytime I run this code I get an error at `byte[] newbyte = Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(mybyte);`. The code used is written below. This code provides some context. I never had this problem and after some research I can't find a clear solution. I hope someone can help me with it.

**Code:**

```
Connection connection = null;
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + path_to_copied_db);
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT `origin_url`,`username_value`,`password_value` FROM `logins`");
ResultSet re = statement.executeQuery();

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while (re.next()) {
    String pass = "";
    try {
        byte[] mybyte = (byte[])re.getBytes("password_value");
        byte[] newbyte = Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(mybyte); //Error on this line:71
        pass = new String(newbyte);
    }catch(Win32Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    builder.append(user + ": " + re.getString("origin_url") + " " + re.getString("username_value") + " " + re.getBinaryStream("password_value") + "\n");
}
```

**Error:**

```
com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Win32Exception: The parameter is incorrect.
at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(Crypt32Util.java:128)
at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(Crypt32Util.java:103)
at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(Crypt32Util.java:90)
at Client.Client.main(Client.java:71)
```

Comment: You should not do this. (1) You should not encrypt passwords, you should hash them. See [tag:password-encryption] for why: in brief, user passworts should not be recoverable by the system. (2) You should hash the password provided by the user and then search the table for a row matching that user and password. If there isn't one, the login is invalid.

Comment: I get that way of thinking, but the goal of the app is that it shows the browers' saved passwords. It's not that the user should enter their password and it checks if it's correct. I know I could use the cryptUnprotectData() method to decrypt the passwords from the browsers' database, but that doesn't seem to work now.